# What's wrong with my showChar method? Simple program intro to methods

Tags: java, methods, char

## //Ch5a Program

'I'm supposed to use a method to display a certain letter of a word input by the user.

I need to use showChar.
There aren't really any obvious errors that I can see and I've worked on it for a couple hours.'

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Ch5a {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What word would you like to analyze?");
        String inputNumberString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What letter would you like to see? (Eg: For the second letter of 'dog', input 2)");
        int inputNo;
        inputNo = Integer.parseInt(inputNumberString);
    /**
     At this point, i have an input number from the user(inputNo) and I have a word from the user(inputString).
     I then print the inputNo for testing.
     */
        System.out.println(inputNo);
    //time to call the method.
        char answer;
    //I declare the character answer.
        answer = showChar(inputString, inputNo);
    //i set it equal to the result of the method.
        System.out.println("The " + inputString +" number character in " + inputNo + " is" + answer);

}
    public static char showChar(String inputString, int inputNo){
     //local variable
        char result;
        result = showChar(inputString, inputNo); //user's chosen character
    //returning whatever i want in place of the method call(in this case, "result")
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your `showChar` method is supposed to do, but it probably shouldn't call itself.

Comment: Have a look at [`String#charAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
public static char showChar(String inputString, int inputNo){
    char result;
    result = inputString.charAt(inputNo -1);   // since index starts at 0
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look at `String.charAt()` method.  I think you want something more like:

```
    public static char showChar(String inputString, int inputNo){

       char result;

       result = inputString.charAt(inputNo - 1); 

       return result;
    }
```

or to simplify:

```
    public static char showChar(String inputString, int inputNo){
       return inputString.charAt(inputNo - 1); 
    }
```

see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_charat.htm for more info

Comment: Should be inputNo - 1, as @Kevin Mee stated

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static char showChar(String inputString, int inputNo){
    inputNo = inputNo-1; // first letter in String has position 0
    if(inputNo<0 || inputNo>=inputString.length())
    {
        // if the number is out of Bounds
        return ' ';
    }
return inputString.charAt(inputNo);
}
```

Comment: Ooo, that's interesting. Thanks.